# Scatterplot error message in R "invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am very new to R (and coding in general), and have encountered this error message a few times now so I wanted to seek an explanation.
An example of when this occurs is creating a scatterplot using 2 columns from a dataframe.

The standard way I have seen to create a basic plot is the format:

```
plot(x,y)
```

So for the columns in my dataframe:

```
plot(my.data$X1, my.data$Y)
```

When I use this code, after typing the `$` symbol it doesn't summon the column names. When it actually works the column names are summoned. The error message I get if I type it in manually to see the output is:

> `"Error in my.data$X1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`

I can produce a scatterplot using the following instead:

```
plot(my.data[,2],my.data[,6])
```

This seems to be a fundamental point that I don't understand so rather than finding work arounds, I would love it if someone could explain this to me as plainly as possible. Is there a way to use the `plot(my.data$X1, my.data$Y)` code on my dataframe? How can I convert my dataframe somehow so that it is compatible? And why would the second line of code work for the data?

Data

```r
structure(c(18.1077698061365, 19.7841550908258, 18.149137536254, 17.0317508777286, 19.1186078461304, 21.7485880018318, 41.594860261788, 33.2876383484106, 34.0027543336534, 39.331379188356, 36.056501743569, 31.3606155556679, 3.69134127639495, 3.40185207030789, 2.26937595847588, 2.15471275215288, 3.279756989501, 1.50583932995163, 79.4801639344262, 84.4114754098361, 96.0573770491803, 88.9333606557377, 84.0475409836066, 88.9909836065574, 38.4959024585249, 29.5966420147911, 32.532480511693, 27.5841655006996, 36.2022786328203, 42.0433739756146, 60, 110, 60, 30, 60, 50), dim = c(6L, 6L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "Y")))
```

Comment: Louise, this could be for a number of reasons including typo in the variable name, accidentally over-writing a frame-object with something else, and having non-frame data in your object. Can you please post the output from `dput(head(my.data))` into your question? It'll help inform what to do next.

Comment: The symptoms suggest `my.data` is a matrix rather than a data frame. Try `my.data <- as.data.frame(my.data)` then your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Allan. I just used is.dataframe and is.matrix, and you're right, it is in fact a matrix. Would it be possible to explain the difference please? It looks identical to other dataframes I've used.

Comment: `$`-indexing only works with `list`s and `data.frame`s, not `matrix`s. In a matrix, all objects/cells must always be the same class, e.g., integer, real, or string. In a frame, in general each _column_ must be a distinct class, but different columns can be different classes. One supposition of a frame is that each "row" is an observation (e.g., columns such as "timestamp", "name", "feet_jumped" are three different classes).

Answer (score 0):

This example code may be helpful to you:

##### 1. Re-create your dataset (in the original Matrix form)

```
my.matrix <- structure(c(18.1077698061365, 19.7841550908258, 18.149137536254, 
                         17.0317508777286, 19.1186078461304, 21.7485880018318, 
                         41.594860261788, 33.2876383484106, 34.0027543336534, 
                         39.331379188356, 36.056501743569, 31.3606155556679, 
                         3.69134127639495, 3.40185207030789, 2.26937595847588, 
                         2.15471275215288, 3.279756989501, 1.50583932995163, 
                         79.4801639344262, 84.4114754098361, 96.0573770491803, 
                         88.9333606557377, 84.0475409836066, 88.9909836065574, 
                         38.4959024585249, 29.5966420147911, 32.532480511693, 
                         27.5841655006996, 36.2022786328203, 42.0433739756146, 
                         60, 110, 60, 30, 60, 50), 
                       dim = c(6L, 6L), 
                       dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "Y")))
```

##### 2. Transform it to a data.frame

This step enables you to use `$` sign to extract columns (vectors) from your dataset.

```
my.data <- as.data.frame(my.matrix)
```

##### 3. Try to plot again:

```
plot(my.data$X1, my.data$Y)
```

You will see:

[image]

Hope this is helpful.